# How can I access tuple index values when creating a OOP method?

Tags: python, oop

I want to set up a class that takes in tuple as variables and then perform actions on that tuple, but I can't get my code to work! Any advice is much appreciated.

I get the error that the tuple index is out of range.

Below is the code that I have written

```
class Line:
    def __init__(self,coor1,coor2):
        self.coor1 = ()
        self.coor2 = ()

    def distance(self):
        return ((self.coor1[1]-self.coor1[0])**2 + (self.coor2[1]-self.coor2[0])**2)**0.5

    def slope(self):
        return (self.coor1[1]-self.coor1[0])/(self.coor2[1]-self.coor2[0])
```

Comment: `coor1` is an empty tuple, did you want `self.coor1 = coor1`?

Comment: Jesus! so simple! yes, that's what I missed. Thanks a lot!